# Koin Update Android Context After Configuration Changed

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin, onconfigurationchanged

I'm working on an application that supports multiple languages so when users change the language we start splash activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`, and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flags then finish the language activity.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(mIntent);
    finish();
```

We have created wrapper class to wrape the application resources

```
class AppResources(private val context: Context): IAppResources {

    override fun getString(resId: Int): String {
        Logger.i("Current locale language is: ${context.resources.configuration.locale.language}")
        return context.getString(resId)
    }

    override fun getStringArray(resId: Int): Array<String> {
        Logger.i("Current locale language is: ${context.resources.configuration.locale.language}")
        return context.resources.getStringArray(resId)
    }

}
```

Then we inject this class using Koin like this

```
factory<IAppResources> {
        Logger.i("Current androidContext language is: ${androidContext().resources.configuration.locale.language}")
        AppResources(androidContext())
    }
```

The issue is that when we get string value from resources we got it with wrong localization as the Koin already started with previouse android `context` and `AppResources` class already inialized with old `context`.
So any suggestion to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `androidContext()` in koin is usually an `Application` `Context`.

I believe the configuration overriding code you have for your multi-language support is only applied to `Activity`.

You need to wrap the application context with your `Configuration` overrides inside the `factory`. E.g. something like

```
factory<IAppResources> {
    val original = androidContext()
    val config = Configuration().apply {
        setTo(original.resources.configuration)
        setLocale(yourLocale)
    }
    return@factory AppResources(original.createConfigurationContext(config))
}
```

Comment: The configuration has been changed successfully the problem is that Koin `androidContext()` is not changed because the `Application.onCreate()` where we start Koin not get called after configuration changed.

Comment: Yes and that's why you need to apply the configuration changes in koin factory, too. Personally I wouldn't use any kind of application context for UI resource access (would use an Activity instead and not have it in koin) but thinking about it you might be just ok with string resources.

Comment: I got your point after you edited your answer and here is what I did `factory(named(LOCALIZED_CONTEXT)) {
        ApplyLanguage().applyLanguage(androidContext(), get<PreferenceDataSource>().getCurrentLanguage())
    }` then `factory<IAppResources> {
        AppResources(get(named(LOCALIZED_CONTEXT)))
    }`